# batch replace spaces between quotes in file and then remove all quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want create a batch to replace spaces with a + sign if the space is in between quotes.  Then I want to remove the quotes from a text file.  How can I accomplish this?

So I want to change a line like this:

```
2016-01-11 14:45:09 Server 127.0.0.1 GET /global/images/logo_small.jpg - 80 - 173.252.120.117 "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-" www.vietnam.ttu.edu 200 200 200 1868 0
```

To this line.

```
2016-01-11 14:45:09 Server 127.0.0.1 GET /global/images/logo_small.jpg - 80 - 173.252.120.117 facebookexternalhit/1.1+(+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) - www.vietnam.ttu.edu 200 200 200 1868 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Windows batch is not suitable for the job. You need regular expressions. Use javascript or perl. In perl f.ex.:   s/"([^"]*)"/blank2plus($1)/ge

Comment: @Henrik. I agree batch is a poor choice, but it could be done. It would require significant code, and be slow. The problem certainly does not *need* regular expressions, but they can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to arrive at a very concise and efficient solution. JREPL is a pure script based (JScript/batch) regular expression text processing utility that runs on any version of Windows from XP onward.

```
jrepl "\q| " "q=!q;''|q?'+':' '" /j /x /t "|" /jbegln "q=false" /f test.txt /o -
```

For this solution I use the `/T` option, which is very similar to the unix tr utility, or the sed `y` command.

I define two search terms, the first for a quote (The `\X` option enables the \q escape sequence), and the second for a space.

The `/J` option treats replacement strings as JScript. The first replacement string for the quote toggles a "q" variable TRUE or FALSE, and replaces the quote with an empty string. The second replacement string conditionally replaces the space with a plus or space, depending on the state of the "q" variable.

The `/JBEGLN` option initializes the "q" variable to FALSE at the beginning of each line.

The `/F` option specifies the input file, and the `/O -` option specifies that the output overwrites the original file.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34732271.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %%a&SET "line="&CALL :process %%a

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "addition=%~1"
IF not DEFINED addition ECHO %line:~1%&GOTO :eof
IF "%~1"==%1 (
 REM quoted
 SET "line=%line% %addition: =+%"
) ELSE (
 SET "line=%line% %addition%"
)
shift
GOTO process
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34732271.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The `echo %%a` shows your one line of data on the screen and the `echo` within the `:process` routine shows that line processed.

Batch is not an ideal language to process strings as it exhibits sensitivity to many symbols. This process should work provided you are happy to have space-strings compressed and the source string does not contain `,` `;`,<kbd>tab</kbd> `%` or any other symbol that `cmd` treats specially.

Comment: There would appear to be no logical refor that behaviour. Perhaps itrelated to the content of the lines?

Comment: The file does use semi-colons and possibility commas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution that walks through the characters in each line in file `line.txt`, replaces all <kbd>SPACE</kbd>s in between a pair of quotation marks `""` by `+` signs and stores the result in `text_new.txt`. The input string may contain any characters, even special ones:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define global constants here:
set "INFILE=line.txt"
set "OUTFILE=line_new.txt"
set "SEARCH= "
set "REPLACE=+"
set "KEEPQUOTES="

set "QUOTE="""
set "QUOTE=%QUOTE:~,1%"
set "QFLAG="
> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INFILE%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        call :SUB LINE
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B

:SUB
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "LINE=!%1!"
set "LINENEW="
set /A "POS=0"
:LOOP
set "CHAR=!LINE:~%POS%,1!"
set /A "POS+=1"
if not defined CHAR (
    echo(!LINENEW!
    endlocal
    exit /B
)
if "!CHAR!"=="!QUOTE!" (
    if defined QFLAG (
        set "QFLAG="
    ) else (
        set "QFLAG=Quoted"
    )
    if defined KEEPQUOTES (
        set "LINENEW=!LINENEW!!CHAR!"
    )
) else if defined QFLAG (
    if "!CHAR!"=="!SEARCH!" (
        set "LINENEW=!LINENEW!!REPLACE!"
    ) else (
        set "LINENEW=!LINENEW!!CHAR!"
    )
) else (
    set "LINENEW=!LINENEW!!CHAR!"
)
goto :LOOP
```